# Can't get three.js EffectComposer to work

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to start doing some postprocessing on my renders with the EffectComposer but I can't get the most basic setup to render to the screen. It just stays blank. I must be looking over something. Does anybody have an idea?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>game</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body {        
        margin: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }

      canvas {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>    
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="viewport"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="three.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="CopyShader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ShaderPass.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="EffectComposer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="RenderPass.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="MaskPass.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var width = document.body.clientWidth;
      var height = document.body.clientHeight;      
      var canvas = document.querySelector('#viewport');
      var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: canvas});
      renderer.setSize(width, height);

      var scene = new THREE.Scene();

      var cube = new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.CubeGeometry(30, 30, 30), 
        new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xFF0000}));
      scene.add(cube);

      var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, width / height, 0.1, 1000);
      camera.position = new THREE.Vector3(60, 60, 60);
      camera.lookAt(cube.position);
      camera.updateMatrix();
      scene.add(camera);      

      var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF);
      pointLight.position = new THREE.Vector3(100, 80, 20);
      scene.add(pointLight);

      var renderPass = new THREE.RenderPass(scene, camera);
      renderPass.renderToScreen = true;      
      var composer = new THREE.EffectComposer(renderer);
      composer.addPass(renderPass);
      renderer.clear();
      composer.render();

      //renderer.render(scene, camera);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I uncomment the last line I get something on the screen.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, Except I can make it render but it renders as a complete mess. Also I don't think that "renderPass.renderToScreen = true;" is actually an option of the renderpass (I know it seems like it should have, as film has it, but if you look at the source for RenderPass.js it does not have a renderToScreen option.

Comment: Did you try my sample because when I use `renderer.render(scene, camera);` here I get my cube on the screen correctly.

Comment: Yeah, what happends if you enable both? 

http://www.cytoweb.co.uk/3ds/examples/freakout.html < that's what happends when I do

Comment: Then it just renders my cube like it should

Comment: wonder if its my shader that is causing my issue.. hmmmm

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, `EffectComposer` is not part of the library -- it's part of the examples. So it's not officially supported.

So yes, you have to "know how it's working behind the hood."

You can fix your problem by adding an extra `CopyPass` like so:

```
var renderPass = new THREE.RenderPass( scene, camera );

var copyPass = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.CopyShader );
copyPass.renderToScreen = true;

var composer = new THREE.EffectComposer( renderer );
composer.addPass( renderPass );
composer.addPass( copyPass );

composer.render( 0.05 );
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, hopefully can use this to fix my issue.

I'm not asking for spoon fed help... But just to check.. Is this issue i'm having (related) http://cytoweb.co.uk/3ds/examples/freakout.html.. A bug or just me getting mixed up?

(That should be a cube, but after running it through the EffectComposer it turns all abstract on me)

Comment: @james Please post a new issue if you are having a problem. But I think you can answer that question yourself by the process of elimination.

Comment: Yeah, I been working on it for a couple of days and have not been able to resolve the issue yet (But it might be I've gone so far wrong that I just need to take a new approach). I'll keep on it :)

Comment: To understand whats going on : the RenderPass only renders to the composer buffer, it has no "renderToScreen" flag. It is not intended to be used alone, hence the need of the minimal CopyShader if your composer is "empty".

Answer (score 1):

I'm having some issues with the EffectComposer aswell.

But I think it purely comes down to not knowing how it's all working behind the hood.

You can fix your issue (as a bit of a hack)

if you add

```
var effectFilm = new THREE.FilmPass( 0, 0, 0, false );
effectFilm.renderToScreen = true;
composer.addPass( effectFilm );
```