# three.js EffectComposer browser window resize issue

Tags: javascript, three.js, rendering

I have a rendering setup where a resizing problem occurs when resizing the browser window.

I render two scenes, one of them for objects with postprocessing effects applied. For the effects I use the THREE.EffectComposer and shaders from the example directory.

The two scene renders are then additively blended with the help of another shader example.

---

See following simplified setup: http://jsbin.com/hibum/18/edit?js,output
(in the HTML part I include a few js sources from the three.js repository)

If you shrink the output panel, then reload the page and again widen the panel, you'll see something like this:

[image: The second scene rendering did not update correctly]

The main scene (blue sphere) did update its rendering size, but the effects scene (orange sphere) still has the same resolution, just upscaled.

I can't find out which render target or renderer (or shader uniform?) needs to be updated at the browser resize event to still correctly output the image after resizing.

For the main composer it works with a `setSize()` call, but if I do that on the effects composer, it won't render the effects scene.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: See how `EffectComposer.reset()` is used in the three.js examples.

Comment: @WestLangley, if I add a ```reset()``` to either the main or effects EffectComposer inside the ```setSize()``` function (the function that's called on browser resize) in my jsbin example, the effects scene is not rendered anymore, only the main scene...
/edit: only ```main.reset();``` in this function renders both scenes, but has no effect on the resize issue

Comment: OK, so you have to figure out why it works correctly in the three.js examples, but not it your code.

Comment: @WestLangley Right, thank you. I did not "re-attach" the render target after resetting the two composers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to reset both EffectComposers and then also reset the `tDiffuse2` uniform of the AdditiveBlendShader:

```
main.reset();  
effects.reset();  

blend.uniforms.tDiffuse2.value = effects.renderTarget2;
```

See http://jsbin.com/hibum/23/edit?js,output

Comment: Can someone explain how the tDiffuse uniform relates to the resolution? I have the same issue except with a different set of shaders, and I have found a few others who have variants of this problem: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30626567/resizing-window-when-using-effectcomposer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13350084/cant-get-three-js-effectcomposer-to-work). It seems like the issues have to EffectComposer reset/resize and/or shader uniforms. The questions have answers, but the answers do not explain why they work so it's difficult to use that to answer new questions.