# THREE.EffectComposer is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, three.js

first time here :) Hello everyone !

I was trying to follow some code to create a volumetric light scattering shader using THREE, trying to reproduce this: https://codepen.io/abberg/pen/pbWkjg

But when I do it, I get a console error saying: 'THREE.EffectComposer is not a constructor'

The issue is that I'm trying to reproduce this in ES6 environnement, using gulp. In order to prevent too much compiling time, I removed THREE from the gulp watch compilation for the duration of the dev, and imported it directly in index.html as follow:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/three/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

I use THREE 0.88.0

Did I miss a plugin ? Search on google didn't lead me to any recent answer about this issue.

Thanks in advance for your answer !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't get three.js EffectComposer to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13350084/cant-get-three-js-effectcomposer-to-work)

Comment: Thanks it was indeed that I missed the plugins

Answer (score 1):

EffectComposer is not included in the three.js bundle you are referencing in your script tag. You will need to add the following:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/three/examples/js/postprocessing/EffectComposer.js"></script>
```

Same idea for adding `OrbitControls` and other unofficial three.js modules.